# Generate random strings in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, random

I need to generate random strings in vb.net, which must consist of (randomly chosen) letters A-Z (must be capitalized) and with random numbers interspersed. It needs to be able to generate them with a set length as well.

Thanks for the help, this is driving me crazy!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you can convert this to VB.NET (which is trivial) I'd say you're good to go (if you can't, use [this](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/) or any other tool for what's worth):

```
/// <summary>
/// The Typing monkey generates random strings - can't be static 'cause it's a monkey.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// If you try hard enough it will eventually type some Shakespeare.
/// </remarks>
class TypingMonkey
{
   private const string legalCharacters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890";

   static Random random = new Random();

   /// <summary>
   /// The Typing Monkey Generates a random string with the given length.
   /// </summary>
   /// <param name="size">Size of the string</param>
   /// <returns>Random string</returns>
   public string TypeAway(int size)
   {
       StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
       char ch;

       for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
       {
           ch = legalCharacters[random.Next(0, legalCharacters.Length)];
           builder.Append(ch);
       }

       return builder.ToString();
    }
}
```

Then all you've got to do is:

```
TypingMonkey myMonkey = new TypingMonkey();
string randomStr = myMonkey.TypeAway(size);
```

Comment: You included lower-case letters and a `.`. *And* you have the Snake Plissken thing going. :)

Comment: Lower-case etc all gone. Snake Plissken will never go :)

Comment: It may be a bit more of a hassle to use, but it works and it amuses me

Comment: Since you know the size of the data, you might as well initialize the StringBuilder with this value. This will avoid unnecessary memory allocations. Great answer though +1.

Comment: @Cyclone the amusement makes it worthwhile ;) - look here if you're curious as to where I currently use this piece of code --> http://github.com/JohnIdol/typingmonkey/blob/master/TypingMonkey/TypingMonkey.cs

Comment: @Meta-Knight thanks :) - looks like someone else didn't like the monkey though, as I just got down-voted ;-/

Comment: Love the monkey - I added a singleton pattern to it so I only have one rather than an infinite supply. Also gave you a bounty for an excellent, useful, and entertaining answer

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you randomize a number 1 to 26 and get the relative letter.

Something like that:

```
Dim output As String = ""
Dim random As New Random()
For i As Integer = 0 To 9
   output += ChrW(64 + random.[Next](1, 26))
Next
```

Edit: ChrW added.

**Edit2: To have numbers as well**

```
    Dim output As String = ""
    Dim random As New Random()

    Dim val As Integer
    For i As Integer = 0 To 9
        val = random.[Next](1, 36)
        output += ChrW(IIf(val <= 26, 64 + val, (val - 27) + 48))
    Next
```

Comment: You forgot about the numbers. :)

Answer (score 2):

**C#**

```
public string RandomString(int length)
{
    Random random = new Random();
    char[] charOutput = new char[length];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        int selector = random.Next(65, 101);
        if (selector > 90)
        {
            selector -= 43;
        }
        charOutput[i] = Convert.ToChar(selector);
    }
    return new string(charOutput);
}
```

**VB.Net**

```
Public Function RandomString(ByVal length As Integer) As String 
    Dim random As New Random() 
    Dim charOutput As Char() = New Char(length - 1) {} 
    For i As Integer = 0 To length - 1 
        Dim selector As Integer = random.[Next](65, 101) 
        If selector > 90 Then 
            selector -= 43 
        End If 
        charOutput(i) = Convert.ToChar(selector) 
    Next 
    Return New String(charOutput) 
End Function
```

Comment: http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/ Use that next time lol, that way I don't have to ;)

Comment: Hey! I linked that as well - and I got the monkey ;)

Comment: You're welcome lol! It even converts back to c# so you can use our vb source in your c# stuff ;). John, I don't see a link anywhere lol? But your monkey is highly amusing, I can't deny it!

Comment: @Cyclone: just switch to C#, already. Come over to the dark side. :)

Comment: quote: [if you can't, use -->this<-- there's the link, not that it matters ;-)

Comment: I *was* making a game in c# cause thats what I was told to make it in, but then I realized that if the server can execute a c# .dll then it can certainly do a vb.net one lol

Comment: @john: Didn't see it, sorry :S. Now I do lol, I love that tool xD

Comment: @MusiGenesis: Your code generates a single random string, once, then never regenerates till you restart the app? Whats up with that lol?

Comment: @Cyclone: in the C# world, creating a new Random object with the empty constructor seeds it with the system time, so the C# version of my function will return a different string every time you call it (unless you call it twice within a few milliseconds and thus seed with the same system time). I'm guessing in VB.Net Random uses the same seed every time until you restart the app. You *really* need to switch to C#, dude. :)

Comment: >(unless you call it twice within a few milliseconds and thus seed with the same system time) Erm, its generating like 1000 pieces of text without any intended pause lol.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
Private Function GenerateString(len as integer) as String
        Dim stringToReturn as String=""
        While stringToReturn.Length<len
           stringToReturn&= Guid.NewGuid.ToString().replace("-","")
        End While
        Return left(Guid.NewGuid.ToString(),len)
End Sub
```

Comment: Clever. Add in the Replace code and deal with strings longer than 1 Guid, and I'll upvote you.

Comment: You could even do away with the `Replace("-","")` call by changing the `.ToString()` to `.ToString("N")`, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/97af8hh4.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Here's a utility class I've got to generate random passwords.  It's similar to JohnIdol's Typing Monkey, but has a little more flexibility in case you want generated strings to contain uppercase, lowercase, numeric or special characters.

```
public static class RandomStringGenerator
{
    private static bool m_UseSpecialChars = false;

    #region Private Variables

    private const int m_MinimumLength = 8;
    private const string m_LowercaseChars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvqxyz";
    private const string m_UppercaseChars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    private const string m_NumericChars = "123456890";
    private const string m_SpecialChars = "~?/@#!£$%^&*+-_.=|";

    #endregion

    #region Public Methods

    /// <summary>
    /// Generates string of the minimum length
    /// </summary>
    public static string Generate()
    {
        return Generate(m_MinimumLength);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Generates a string of the specified length
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="length">The number of characters to generate</param>
    public static string Generate(int length)
    {
        return Generate(length, Environment.TickCount);
    }

    #endregion

    #region Private Methods

    /// <summary>
    /// Generates a string of the specified length using the specified seed
    /// </summary>
    private static string Generate(int length, int seed)
    {
        // Generated strings must contain at least 3 of the following character groups: uppercase letters, lowercase letters
        // numerals, and special characters (!, #, $, £, etc)

        // The generated string must be at least 4 characters  so that we can add a single character from each group.
        if (length < 4) throw new ArgumentException("String length must be at least 4 characters");

        StringBuilder SB = new StringBuilder();

        Random rand = new Random(seed);

        // Ensure that we add all of the required groups first
        SB.Append(GetRandomCharacter(m_LowercaseChars, rand));
        SB.Append(GetRandomCharacter(m_UppercaseChars, rand));
        SB.Append(GetRandomCharacter(m_NumericChars, rand));

        if (m_UseSpecialChars)
            SB.Append(GetRandomCharacter(m_SpecialChars, rand));

        // Now add random characters up to the end of the string
        while (SB.Length < length)
        {
            SB.Append(GetRandomCharacter(GetRandomString(rand), rand));
        }

        return SB.ToString();
    }

    private static string GetRandomString(Random rand)
    {
        int a = rand.Next(3);
        switch (a)
        {
            case 1:
                return m_UppercaseChars;
            case 2:
                return m_NumericChars;
            case 3:
                return (m_UseSpecialChars) ? m_SpecialChars : m_LowercaseChars;
            default:
                return m_LowercaseChars;
        }
    }

    private static char GetRandomCharacter(string s, Random rand)
    {
        int x = rand.Next(s.Length);

        string a = s.Substring(x, 1);
        char b = Convert.ToChar(a);

        return (b);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

To use it:

```
string a = RandomStringGenerator.Generate();   // Generate 8 character random string
string b = RandomStringGenerator.Generate(10); // Generate 10 character random string
```

This code is in C# but should be fairly easy to convert to VB.NET using a [code converter](http://converter.telerik.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Just be simple.  for vb just do:

```
Public Function RandomString(size As Integer, Optional validchars As String = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz") As String
    If size < 1 Or validchars.Length = 0 Then Return ""
    RandomString = ""
    Randomize()
    For i = 1 To size
        RandomString &= Mid(validchars, Int(Rnd() * validchars.Length) + 1, 1)
    Next
End Function
```

This function allows for a base subset of chars to use or user can choose anything.  For example you could send ABCDEF0123456789 and get random Hex. or "01" for binary.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it's the top answer already converted to VB!

```
Private Function randomStringGenerator(size As Integer)
    Dim random As Random = New Random()
    Dim builder As Text.StringBuilder = New Text.StringBuilder()
    Dim ch As Char
    Dim legalCharacters As String = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890"

    For cntr As Integer = 0 To size
        ch = legalCharacters.Substring(random.Next(0, legalCharacters.Length), 1)
        builder.Append(ch)
    Next
    Return builder.ToString()
End Function
```